# How to send a message to everyone who has used a specific command? - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a bot for events that my server often holds. I'm trying to make it so that whoever has used a specific command gets a DM on a specific date. For this instance, it's **<test**.

```js
const TestSet = new Set();

if (msg.member.roles.cache.has("694103248163962880")) {
    msg.channel.send("Test");
    TestSet.add(msg.author.id);
}
```

This is what happens when the command is run. I'm stuck on how I'll be able to run this command and send a message to everyone in my server who used that command. Below is what I have so far.

```js
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.minute = 46;
rule.hour = [08];
rule.date = 22;
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the user id's of the people you want to send your message to, you can use: `() => {TestSet.forEach(id => {client.users.fetch(id).send("Your message")})}` to send your message to every user in `TestSet`. You would place this in your pre-existing code like so:

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.minute = 46;
rule.hour = [08];
rule.date = 22;
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, () => {TestSet.forEach(id => {client.users.fetch(id).send("Your message")})});
```